# Can not debugging in flutter

Tags: flutter, windows

I'm working on developing Windows desktops these days.
Debugging worked normally on the flutter, but one day the debugging doesn't work normally.
There is no action after recording as below.

[Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...]

==> debugging end...

But, debugging through the command leaves a normal log

flutter run -d windows
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...

A Dart VM Service on Windows is available at: http://127.0.0.1:52646/nMK2cU9GTqU=/
flutter: [D] TIME: 2023-12-06T16:21:52.184102 app state: AppState.normal newNotification:true

==> debugging start...

What did I do wrong?
Or what should I do?

- flutter clean -> flutter pub get
- flutter sdk re-install
- visualstudio 2019 re-install
- vscode clean( with cache )

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Android Studio, you only need to press (Debug "main.dart") button from top bar and apply break point at desire line in code where you need to debugbing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RUQ5.png)

Comment: Hello, the question is asked for an VSCode IDE

Comment: Hello, the question is asked for an VSCode IDE